# Orden de ejecucion de métodos

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

Controller

```
$scope.loadAge = function (age) {
    $scope.age = age * 2.2568;
}

$scope.sum = function () {
    $scope.result= $scope.ageResult + 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" ng-init="loadAge('${sheetId}')">   
  <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="ageResult" ng-init="ageResult=age"/>    
  <div data-ng-init="sum()">
.....
```

Pero siempre entra primero en el método sum

Answer (score 1):

[`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) no garantiza un orden de ejecución. Tendras que definir el orden de ejecución por tu propia cuenta ejecutando los métodos al final del controlador:

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[])

app.controller("TestController", function($scope){
  $scope.age = 0;
  $scope.loadAge = function (age) {
      $scope.age = age * 2.2568;
  }

  $scope.sum = function () {
      $scope.ageResult= $scope.ageResult + 100;
  }
  
  $scope.loadAge(12);
  $scope.sum();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">   
  <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="ageResult" ng-init="ageResult=age"/>    

  {{age}}
 </div>
```